# Unity configuration with parameter and create instance at once

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'd like pass `myContext` to `Business` and `Facade`. In `Facade`. I'd like create an instance of `Business` with `myContext` in argument.

I got this error :
The Facade does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (`MyContext`).

I tried something like this too but not working :

```
public class Facade : IFacade
{
    readonly IBusiness business;
    readonly MyContext myContext;

    public Facade(MyContext context,IBusiness business)
    {
        this.myContext = context
        this.business = business;
    }
}
```

My current code :

```
public class Facade : IFacade
{
    readonly IBusiness business;

    public Facade(IBusiness business)
        => this.business = business;
}

public class Business : IBusiness
{
    readonly Idal dal;

    public Business(IDal dal)
        => this.dal = dal;
}

public static IUnityContainer Init(MyContext myContext)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IFacade, Facade>
        (new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(myContext));

    container.RegisterType<IBusiness, Business>
        (new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(myContext));

    return container;
}
```

Comment: Did answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you looking for this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new SomeClass() { SomeId = 10 };
        var container = ConfigureContainer(context);
        var facadeInstance = container.Resolve<IFacade>();
        Console.WriteLine(facadeInstance.ShowContextId());
    }

    public static IUnityContainer ConfigureContainer(SomeClass context)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IFacade, Facade>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter(typeof(SomeClass), context)));

        return container;
    }
}

public interface IFacade
{
    int ShowContextId();
}

public class Facade : IFacade
{
    public readonly SomeClass _context;

    public Facade(SomeClass context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int ShowContextId() => _context?.SomeId ?? 0;
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
}
```